# Hibernate criteria query. After creating a sub-criteria, can I return to the original criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

In Hibernate tutorial there is an [example of sub-criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

But after creating the sub-criteria on "kittens", can I return to the original one? If I write a line `.add(Restrictions.like("id", 1))` , does it restrict Cat.id or Cat.kittens.id? Is there a way to go back and restrict cat.id again?

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
    .createCriteria("kittens") 
        .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") ) 
    .add(Restrictions.like("id", 1)) // on Cat.id or Cat.kittens.id?
    .list();
```

Comment: I probably find a solution, I can always use alias for a criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion add a critiria like below code

```
    List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class).createCriteria("cat")
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
.createCriteria("kittens") 
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") ) 
.add(Restrictions.like("cat.id", 1)) // on Cat.id or Cat.kittens.id?
.list();
```

Hope this will help.